# Why am I getting 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException' when I run 'lein trampoline'

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I use lein trampoline to quickly execute my tests.  The steps involved with the error I see go as thus:

- in my .bash_profile: `export LEIN_FAST_TRAMPOLINE=y`
- in my repo: `lein trampoline test`

This works fine most of the time on Macbook running OS X 10.9.5, but every now and then after closing and opening the laptop, I get the following error:

`$ lein trampoline test
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/r8/qvl5rf_j0336y2y2rsnxb7_w0000gr/T/form-init4452180728363992495.clj (No such file or directory)`

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: What version of Leiningen are you running? The problem may be caused [by this bug](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1683), that has been resolved and updating to the latest version may solve your problem.

Comment: @Symfrog 2.5.0, which was released 9/14/2014.  I see 2.5.1 was released 1/9/2015, but hasn't yet been updated in Homebrew.  I'll give that a shot the next time I run into this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[The leiningen faster wiki page](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Faster) notes that two things will clear the fast trampoline cache:

- changing the `project.clj` file
- deleting the `target` folder inside of the project

I chose to do the latter, and this resolved the issue for me.  This sporadic nature seems due to files in `/private/var/folders` being cleared if they [aren't accessed in 3 days](http://blog.magnusviri.com/what-is-var-folders.html) in OS X.